# Recoverable fatal error: ini_set(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name() - Drupal

Tags: drupal

I got this error once run my Drupal Project,

> **Recoverable fatal error**: ini_set(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name() in C:\xampp\htdocs\jordan\sites\default\settings.php on line 145

Comment: This helps https://forum.pkp.sfu.ca/t/ini-set-cannot-set-user-save-handler-by-ini-set/60700

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an older Drupal version which does not run on PHP 7.x. You have to switch back to PHP 5.6 (or switch to a newer Drupal version but that will be more complicated). Usually you can do this in the administration interface of the company where you host your web site.

For example, in the "Odin Automation" panel used by the "magic online" group, you go into the section "Hosting" of the left menu; then, in the list of hosted domains, choose **Action** => "PHP config", and then, on the next screen, you will see the setting of the PHP version which you can choose from a selection list. You will have to choose a 5.x version, the latest (and only one not to be "not recommended") being 5.6.